# Getting detailed city/region names from OpenStreetMap (OSM) tile API

Tags: openstreetmap, layers, tiles, api, web-service

I want a tile for a region. I have the coordinates. I used a [calculator webservice](https://oms.wff.ch/calc.htm) to convert lat/long to z/x/y.

I'm using the OSM service like this: https://tile.openstreetmap.org/8/137/83.png :

`curl "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{8}/{137}/{83}.png" --output out.png`

Problem is, this tile does not include detailed names of regions and cities. I can't use a higher zoom level since it reduces my target area. How can I control the details of the request?

I searched the [documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) but couldn't find the answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I removed my 2nd question...I'll ask it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to influence how these map tiles will look like. These are raster tiles, created by a renderer with a pre-defined stylesheet. Depending on the zoom level and the location, some of them are even pre-rendered.

However, you can switch to a different tile server that uses a stylesheet with more details. For alternative tile servers see the [Leaflet Provider Demo](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) or [Tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles#Servers) in the OSM wiki.

Another alternative would be switching to [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) where you can influence the style of the map.

Please also make sure to read the tile usage policy for the tile server you are choosing.